# Multiplayer JAVASCRiPT game with NODEJS backend - implementing STEAM auto login on game launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, game-development, steam, steam-web-api

I am developing a game thats basically a website(frontend html, js, css) with a nodejs backend. It works like charm, the game can be played in any browser.

I found a way to convert this website to an executable (.exe). It works the exact same way as if it was running inside a browser but now, its an executable that I can deploy to steam. So the game can be found on steam, can be downloaded there and played.

Right now, the login procedure is part of the website. I can enter a username and password and I am authenticated against my own backend.

Now comes my question: Is it possible to pass the steam login credentials to the game on startup? This way the player would not need to authenticate with outsideofsteam credentials and can play directly with steam user id. On the server side I could then connect the steam user id to the character of the game.

Any help/hints/ideas are very appreciated. Thank you in advance! :)

I didnt try anything yet because I did not find anything that comes close to my specific usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan on using Steam to distribute your game, you'll want to use the [Steam SDK](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk).  It's a C library, but there's an (extremely limited) NodeJS binding called [steamworks.js](https://github.com/ceifa/steamworks.js) that should be enough to get you started with linking steam accounts either directly to your game or sharing them with your existing account system.

Comment: hi kevin, thank you for your reply. I understand :) So I can use this on the server side to link the accounts from my game to the steam accounts in the backend. sounds great. Ill start with this.

Answer (score 0):

Steam provides an [OpenID web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#website) which you can use to authenticate registered users in your game. The users would click the link to login by Steam and then Steam would generate a session ticket which can be stored on your server and used to validate with Steam's APIs.

Comment: Hi Kyohei :) Thank you for your reply!
This information I could already find out. I think I am too stupid to understand with the given information from that link, how to use the openid web api.

I did not find a single example code of that. Would you be so kind as to support me here with at least a very tiny starting guide on how to do that thing on client side in javascript?